# powerbuilder query to sql query

Tags: sql, powerbuilder

I want to convert this powerbuilder query to SQL query but I am not getting any proper tutorial.I tried to convert this Powerbuilder query into sql based query but I am not very much sure about it.

```
PBSELECT( VERSION(400) TABLE(NAME=~"childpart~" ) COLUMN(NAME=~"childpart.child_part_no~") COLUMN(NAME=~"childpart.part_no~") COLUMN(NAME=~"childpart.component_qty~") COLUMN(NAME=~"childpart.regist_person~") COLUMN(NAME=~"childpart.regist_date~") COLUMN(NAME=~"childpart.regist_time~") COLUMN(NAME=~"childpart.upd_person_name~") COLUMN(NAME=~"childpart.upd_date~") COLUMN(NAME=~"childpart.upd_time~")WHERE(    EXP1 =~"childpart.child_part_no~"   OP =~"=~"    EXP2 =~":p_child_part_no~"    LOGIC =~"and~" ) WHERE(    EXP1 =~"childpart.part_no~"   OP =~"=~"    EXP2 =~":p_part_no~" )
```

SQL converted query

```
SELECT childpart.child_part_no ,childpart.part_no ,childpart.component_qty ,childpart.regist_person ,childpart.regist_date ,childpart.regist_time ,childpart.upd_person_name ,childpart.upd_date ,childpart.upd_time FROM childpart WHERE EXP1 = childpart.child_part_no OR EXP2 = p_child_part_no and EXP1 = childpart.part_no OR EXP2 = p_part_no
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you view the Query in PowerBuilder, simply click on Design -> Convert to Syntax

Comment: I have just .srd files and from this .srd files I extracting these queries & trying to convert it in SQL based query

Comment: You can import these .srd files to PowerBuilder. Or does everything has to happen programmatically?

Comment: Yes Everything has to happen programmatically, I don't have powerbuilder  software , I have files(.srd,.srw) & based on these files I need to automate the conversion of Powerbuilder queries to SQL based query.

Comment: If there is any online or offline tool that can convert the PB queries to SQL query will be very helpful for me for verification of my conversion

Comment: Well if it was saved using covert to syntax it would actually just show the select when editing the file. I don't know of a tool like that, you might have to look around a bit. Otherwise you could go through the string and write your own function to retrieve the query. Doesn't look too hard, though you have to consider that it can also include groups and sorts and what not

Answer (score 0):

Correct converted query:

```
SELECT childpart.child_part_no,childpart.part_no,childpart.component_qty,childpart.regist_person,childpart.regist_date,childpart.regist_time,childpart.upd_person_name,childpart.upd_date,childpart.upd_time 
FROM  childpart   
WHERE childpart.child_part_no=:p_child_part_no AND childpart.part_no=:p_part_no
```

Comment: can you add a little more context what you actually did to fix the issue?